# XSL to filter duplicates

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I  am trying generate a PDF using XSL. But I dont want duplicates(it should not be displayed back to back) , only for value=Started.

Below is the XSL snippet where I display the query result (string_1 column).

```
    <xsl:for-each select="root/query1/row">
                            <fo:table-row height="0.9cm">
                            <xsl:if test="event_name = 'Started'">
                                   <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" 
                                    number-columns-spanned="5">
                                        <fo:block font-family="Courier" color="Blue" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" text-align="center">
                                           <xsl:value-of select="string_1"/>
                                        </fo:block>

                                    </fo:table-cell>    
                                </xsl:if>

    </xsl:for-each>
```

Eg,
My query1 may give results like:

## String_1

======

Started

In Progress

Complete

Started

Started

In Progress

In Progress

Complete

## My PDF should be

=========

Started

In Progress

Complete

Started

In Progress

In Progress

Complete

Sorry if I didn't provide much information. I am new to XSL.

Comment: You need to provide the input XML that generated the output you show.

Comment: You have 2 back to back `In Progress` rows in the desired result. Surely this conflicts with the requirement?

Comment: The given XSL is incorrect. There is no closing `<fo:table-row>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, how your input XML exactly looks like, but you should be able to adapt from this XML

```
<root>
<query1>
<row>
<string_1>Started</string_1>
</row>
<row>
<string_1>In Progress</string_1>
</row>
<row>
<string_1>In Progress</string_1>
</row>
<row>
<string_1>In Progress</string_1>
</row>
<row>
<string_1>Complete</string_1>
</row>
</query1>
</root>
```

and this XSLT:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/query1/row">
 #>   <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::*[1]=string_1)">
        <fo:table-row height="0.9cm">
          <!-- <xsl:if test="event_name = 'Started'"> -->
          <fo:table-cell border-style="solid" border-width="0.5pt" number-columns-spanned="5">
            <fo:block font-family="Courier" color="Blue" font-size="10pt" font-weight="normal" text-align="center">
              <xsl:value-of select="string_1" />
            </fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          <!-- </xsl:if> -->
        </fo:table-row>
  #>  </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

I have highlighted the important lines by #>. I have commented out one of the if-statements which seems to be there for doing different formatting on *started* nodes.

`preceding-sibling::*[1]` gives you the last processed node. It is compared to `string_1` which is the current node. If it is different (`not()`), it should become part of the output.